# присваивание введенного с клавиатуры значения 2-м переменным

Tags: c#, переменные

Вопрос очень глупый.
Как введенное значение с клавиатуры присвоить сразу двум разным переменным, используемым в разных классах. Так чтобы консоль не ждала повторного ввода,как реализовано в данном примере:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите коэффициент усиления: \nGain=");
        Active.Gain = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Passive.Gain = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 5):

Просто присвойте `Passive.Gain` значение `Active.Gain`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите коэффициент усиления: \nGain=");
Active.Gain = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Passive.Gain = Active.Gain;
```

Comment: спасибо. элементарно как

Comment: Исключительно для читабельности кода можно ввести переменную и присвоить ей ввод.